# Amount of ways of putting socks on first and then shoes

Tags: combinatorics

The question was:
A spider has 8 legs. It wants to put on 8 different socks and 8 different shoes on each leg, but it must put a sock on before a shoe. What is the total amount of ways?
I thought it would be $8! \times 8!$, since we fix socks, then arrange socks. Then fix shoes, then arrange shoes.

However, my lecturer said it was this:
Form a 16 digit string with only digits $1$ to $8$.
An example is:
$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,3,4,1,5,9,8,7,6$
THe total amount of ways of having a string of this form will be $16!/(2!)^8$.

I don't see why my answer is incorrect and why their one is. Their explanation was that
"each digit represents that leg. For example, the first digit $1$ is corresponding to putting a sock on the 1st leg. The second $1$ that appears will be the shoe."

Answer (score 4):

His result $$\frac{16!}{(2!)^8}$$
comes from the fact that you can arrange the socks and shoes in any order, but only half of the orders will put sock A on before shoe A, half of those will put on sock B before shoe B, and so on. This can be extended to the spider having to put on a sock, then a shoe, then a snowshoe. In that case, there are six possible orders to put on the sock, then the sock protector, then the shoe, but only the order sock, shoe, and snowshoe works, meaning that only $\frac1{3!}=\frac16$ out of the possible orders will be correct. You do this for each of the eight legs. Your result of $8!\cdot8!$ only counts the ordering of putting on all the socks, then all the shoes **after the spider has put on all eight socks**. For instance, your result would not count putting on the sock and the corresponding shoe immediately afterwards.

Comment: I see. If we could put on shoes before socks, we wouldn't divide right? And each digit will be distinct? So we have something like $1_1,1_2$?

Comment: @similarityinvariance1 Yes, if we could put on socks and shoes in any order, we would have $16!$ ways to do it. I am having trouble understanding your other questions.

Comment: A better extension might be: sock, shoe, snowshoe.  Or you can do: sock, shoe, ski boot, ski.

Comment: Thank you. Which part of my reasoning for $8!\times 8!$ is incorrect?

Comment: @AlgorithmsX what about if I just want to know the number of combinations of socks and shoes, with socks before shoes, INDEPENDENTLY OF THE ORDER OF PUTTING THEM ON, i.e., putting sock1 then sock2 and then shoe1 and then shoe2 is the same as putting sock1 then shoe1 then sock2 then shoe2?

Comment: @AlgorithmsX Moreover, isn't this approach considering that every sock has only one corresponding shoe? what if a sock can be matched with any shoe?

Comment: @Marco First Question: Removing the order requirement means there's only one "way" to put them on. It's like asking how many ways can I arrange the numbers 1 - 10 where order doesn't matter. Second Question: The corresponding shoe for each sock is the one that goes on the same leg. If you want to count sock/shoe stuff differently if it goes on different legs, multiply by $(8!)^2$.